# Joomla user groups, viewing access levels based on subscription

Tags: php, joomla, permissions, grouping

I am curently developing a subscription based website on Joomla. It all went smooth until i had to deal with viewing access levels and user groups.
So here it goes.

I have 3 types of subscription.

1. Regular
2. VIP + Regular
3. VIP Only

I also have 2 pages:

1. Regular Page
2. VIP Page

The Regular users should be able to access only the Regular Page.
Ther VIP+Regular should be able to access both pages.
The VIP Only should be able to access only the VIP Page.

I have tried different variations of user groups and access levels, but with no success.

On my subscription extension I am able to only select one user group on payment success.

Can anyone help me with this problem?
I really need some explanations also if it is possible.

This is my current setup:

**USER GROUPS:**
-Registered
--Subscribed
---VIP

**VIEWING ACCESS LEVELS:**

Subscribed:
-Subscribed

VIP:
-Subscribed
--VIP

**VIEWING ACCESS FOR THE PAGES:**

Regular Page: Subscribed

VIP Page: VIP

The problem is that i can't get the pages to shown correctly based on the above.
The VIP Page is currently shown for the Regular subscribed users.
The Regular Page is also shown for the VIP Only subscribed users

Thanks.

Comment: You've described the scenario, but what is the actual problem here? Are you trying to say that **VIP + Regular** isn't working as the user only gets assigned to 1 user group?

Comment: sorry for that. i'm a mess at this hour :). I've edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: Have you by any chance accidentally made the VIP user group a child of the Registered one?

Comment: the VIP user group is a child of Subscribed user group, wich in turn is a child of the Registered user group.

Comment: That's the issue then. I would suggest making `Subscribed` the parent user group, then making `VIP` and `Registered` separate children of the parent.

Comment: Did that. Still the same problem. If i am a Registered/Subscribed user i can still see the VIP Page (the viewing access level is set on the VIP group only.

Comment: Have you ensured that when you are set to the Registered group that you are not also set to the VIP group? I only ask as in Joomla, users can be assigned to multiple groups

Comment: Yes. Do you have a skype account so i can send you some screenshots?

Comment: Indeed I do, however I'm not able to look into things in depth as I'm currently at work. `charlie.lodder`

Comment: there is no problem. it might be just a simple fix due to my poor explanation of the problem?